# How to find logs from bazel's previous runs

Tags: bazel

I'm interested in seeing if bazel ran in the recent past. Where can I find general logging for past bazel build/run/fetch (maybe somewhere in /var/log)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find logs in the [output base](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/output_directories.html) for the workspace, which for Linux is typically `$HOME/.cache/bazel/_bazel_$USER/<MD5 sum of workspace path>/`

You can find the output base for a workspace by running `bazel info output_base` in that workspace. Note though that there's a `command.log` file which contains the output of the last command, and `bazel info` is itself a command, so that will overwrite `command.log`. You can do `echo -n $(pwd) | md5sum` in a bazel workspace to get the md5, or find the README files in the output base directories which say what workspace each is for.